# Is there a built in python function to escape a string of unicode characters into unicode escape sequences "\uXXXX\uXXXX\uXXXX"?

Tags: python, unicode

Like repr(), except converting into \uXXXX instead of \x00

*edited title

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a built in function that escapes a string of unicode characters into unicode escape sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

repr() works fine on Unicode strings. For printable ASCII characters, it will print the character, and for unprintable characters, it will print the Unicode escape sequence.

Comment: Not in Python 2.x, `repr(u'ä') == "u'\\xe4'"`

Comment: When I do `repr('α')` it prints out `\xce\xb1`, but is it possible to get it to print `\u03B1` instead?

Comment: That works! Thanks so much! It wasn't mentioned in the functions library in docs.python.com though, where did you find out about that? Is there a better documentation somewhere else?

Comment: @philhag `repr('ä'.decode('utf-16')) == "u'\\ua4c3'"`, it's just not guessing the right encoding when you don't give it explicitly

Comment: Read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings and http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html to get a better understanding of Unicode in Python.