# Python enforce unicode escape

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

how do I enforce unicode escape in python?

I have the unicode string `u'aä'` or `u'a\u00e4'` and I want it to be represented as `a\u00e4`. The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745521/is-there-a-built-in-python-function-to-escape-a-string-of-unicode-characters-into) doesn't work for me:

```
>>> repr(u'a\u00e4')
"u'a\\xe4'"
```

From my understanding the following attempt should be the correct solution (but isn't):

```
>>> u'a\u00e4'.encode('unicode-escape')
'a\\xe4'
```

I tried it with python 2.6 and 2.7 on OS X and with 2.6 on Debian Squeeze.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode characters below 256 are always encoded with `\x` in their `repr()`esentation, as it is the least space-consuming.

Nevertheless, they are unicode because of the `u'` at the start. It is just a matter of representation.

If you want it nevertheless, you could do

```
print repr(u'a\u00e4').replace('\\x','\\u00')
```

.